# How to Exactly surround words with HTML Tags in python

Tags: python, string

Now I have these variables and their respective values right here.

```
s = '''
vinyl I had to go to Miami. The size of the ball is huge also the vinyl cutters.
I have a computer and it is only 1.
Another vinyl

vinylDiesel
'''

data =[
"vinyl",
"size",
"vinyl cutters",
"computer",
"1",
"vinyl",
"5"
]
```

Now what I wanted to happen is for **every word** in the **data** variable that it could be surrounded with specific **HTML Tags** in the **"s"** variable. Now take note that the tags pretty much depend on what I want but for this example let's just use `<tag></tag>` & `<sub></sub>` for ease.

Now originally I just wanted to have an output like this. **(See the image)**

[image]

But **before** we can achieve what's on the Image we need to surround those words with the **CORRECT** **HTML Tags**. **Why is that?**, It's because I am trying to display the result in a [PYQT5 QTextEdit Widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html). Since using HTML is the way to add some stylesheet then that is what I am doing.

Now in order to have that result in the Image. I need help to create a program that would generate an output like this.

**Expected Output:**

```
(<tag>vinyl<tag>)<sub>1</sub> I had to go to Miami. The (<tag>size</tag>)<sub>2</sub> of the ball is huge also the (<tag>(<tag>vinyl</tag>)<sub>1</sub> cutters</tag>)<sub>3</sub>.
I have a (<tag>computer</tag>)<sub>4</sub> and it is only (<tag>1</tag>)<sub>5</sub>.
Another (<tag>vinyl<tag>)<sub>1</sub>

(<tag>vinyl</tag>)<sub>1</sub>Diesel
```

Then once this is done then I can just simply set the HTML code of the *[QTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html)* widget to that of the **Expected Output** then we would have the output from the image.

### What I have tried so far.

```
import re
s = '''
vinyl I had to go to Miami. The size of the ball is huge also the vinyl cutters.
I have a computer and it is only 1.
Another vinyl

vinylDiesel
'''


data =[
"vinyl",
"size",
"vinyl cutters",
"computer",
"1",
"vinyl",
"5"
]

for i,p in enumerate(data):
    name = p
    html_element_name ="span"
    color = "blue"

    html_attrs={"style": f"color:{color};font-weight: bold;"}

    sub_num = f"<sub style='font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;'>{i+1}</sub>"

    html_start_tag = '('+"<" + html_element_name + " " + " ".join(["%s='%s'" % (k, html_attrs[k]) for k in html_attrs]) + ">"
    html_end_tag = "</" + html_element_name + ">"+')'+sub_num

    to_replace_with = '  '+html_start_tag+f"{name}"+html_end_tag+'  '

    s = re.sub(fr"{name}",to_replace_with, s)


print(s)
```

Comment: You have `vinyl` twice in your `data`, is that the case in your real data? Does it contain duplicates that you want to keep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
def to_tags(s, data, p = []):
   new_s = ''
   while s:
      if (k:=[(i, a) for i, a in enumerate(data, 1) if s.startswith(a) and a not in p]):
         i, sb = max(k, key=lambda x:len(x[-1]))
         new_s += f'(<tag>{to_tags(sb, data, p + [sb])}</tag>)<sub>{i}</sub>'
         s = s[len(sb):]
      else:
         new_s, s = new_s+s[0], s[1:]
   return new_s

print(to_tags(s, data))
```

Output:

```
'\n(<tag>vinyl</tag>)<sub>1</sub> I had to go to Miami. The (<tag>size</tag>)<sub>2</sub> of the ball is huge also the (<tag>(<tag>vinyl</tag>)<sub>1</sub> cutters</tag>)<sub>3</sub>.\nI have a (<tag>computer</tag>)<sub>4</sub> and it is only (<tag>1</tag>)<sub>5</sub>.\nAnother (<tag>vinyl</tag>)<sub>1</sub>\n\n(<tag>vinyl</tag>)<sub>1</sub>Diesel\n'
```

Comment: The surrounding of the tags work great!, also the assigning of the ```<sub></sub>``` value is cool as well. I forgot to mention that for example "vinyl" whatever the index value of it + 1 will be the ```<sub></sub>``` value of all vinyl.
But for some other words it doesn't correspond thought. Just a sec I'll send in a link

Comment: Here is the link by the way. How can we make the <sub></sub> value of every word depend on it's location from the list **+ 1**?
[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IGOh_uKBpDoOQwaUSowJIdgo8azDZOGmONglWTIRrIU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @IceBear Please see my recent edit.